# Official Status Site/Page/Banner

Tags: feature-request, status

It would be useful to have an official status displayed somewhere.

A banner on all stackapps.com pages, or a specific page that we could view to see the status of the API.

Just now I tried to view some help docs and got empty responses. API requests are also not working for me. If we had a flag like this I'd know immediately if it's my network or the API that's messed up.

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting empty responses due to HTTp 406? Look at this question - http://stackapps.com/questions/59/keep-getting-http-406

Comment: @Franci, I am getting a 406, but my request is still valid.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the site **is** in beta. I agree that some sort of status page would be nice, but if it had to be manually updated, it probably wouldn't be.

Also, the API will probably go up and down so quickly, it would be really annoying to have to update it manually, for like 10 seconds, and then update it again. I'd rather them be spending that time actually working on the site.

A little downtime here or there isn't that bad for a beta run.

Comment: Oh definitely not a manual status site. I'm talking about something more automated. I could just write one that pings the API every 30 seconds or so, but it would be nice to have an official status exposed in this site.

Answer (score -1):

Try going to http://m.stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com to see if anything there is loading properly. (That's my mobile site that uses the API.)

If it is, your network is the problem. Otherwise, the API is down.

Comment: The API stuff on your site doesn't work properly for me. I keep getting an error that refers to your `foreach` statement.

Comment: @Max: Ya, Google problems :)